# prettyphoto how to open specific image with api

Tags: prettyphoto

I am using this example from the documentation:

```
api_images = ['images/fullscreen/image1.jpg','images/fullscreen/image2.jpg','images/fullscreen/image3.jpg'];
api_titles = ['Title 1','Title 2','Title 3'];
api_descriptions = ['Description 1','Description 2','Description 3']
$.prettyPhoto.open(api_images,api_titles,api_descriptions);
```

For example, how could I make image number 2 in array the starting point when prettyphoto opens, so it can also go backwards from that point as well?
(I could put it on first place in array but then I have mixed my content)

Comment: +1 An excellent question for sure.

Answer (score 4):

Although it's not documented, it's available in the API like this:

```
$.prettyPhoto.changePage(3) //for the 4th image (zero based)
```

Call that right after you open the set.